# Некорректное заполнение DataGrid

Tags: wpf

У меня такая проблема которую пока не могу решить.

Есть `DataGrid` с тремя столбцами:
Первый столбец - это `DataGridTemplateColumn` в котором вставлен `ComboBox`. 
Второй столбец содержит числа, соответствующие списку элементов из `ComboBox`. 
Третий столбец предназначен для ввода пользователем чисел.

Логика такова:
 `ComboBox` содержится несколько имен, а во втором столбце для каждого имени свое число. При выборе другого имени в `ComboBox`, число во втором столбце соответственно меняется. При вводе значений в третий столбец добавляется следующая строка и так далее.

Использовал именно `DataGridTemplateColumn` со вставленным `ComboBox`, т.к. хочу реализовать возможность выбрать элемент из списка в `ComboBox`, введя текст в текстовом поле, установив `IsEditable = true`.

Проблема такова:
Во второй столбец "Значение 1" сами значения не биндится, т.е. значения отсутствуют. А когда вношу значения в третий столбец - "Значение 2" и добавляется следующая строка, то текст из `ComboBox` исчезает.

Вот картинка того что получается:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как это победить не знаю..
Привожу весь имеющийся у меня код:

MainWindow.xaml:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        Title="MainWindow"
        Width="600"
        Height="525"
        WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen"
        mc:Ignorable="d">
    <Grid>
        <DataGrid x:Name="DataGrid3"
                  HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                  VerticalAlignment="Top"
                  AutoGenerateColumns="False"
                  CanUserResizeRows="False"
                  GridLinesVisibility="All"
                  ItemsSource="{Binding Examples}"
                  SelectionMode="Extended"
                  SelectionUnit="Cell">
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTemplateColumn x:Name="ComboBoxColomn3"
                                        Width="200"
                                        Header="Название">
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <Grid>
                                <ComboBox DisplayMemberPath="Name"
                                          IsEditable="True"
                                          ItemsSource="{Binding Employees,
                                                                RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor,
                                                                                               AncestorType={x:Type Window}}}"
                                          SelectedItem="{Binding Employee,
                                                                 Mode=TwoWay,
                                                                 UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
                            </Grid>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn>
                <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Employee.Value1}"
                                    Header="Значение 1"
                                    IsReadOnly="True" />
                <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Employee.Value2, Mode=TwoWay}" Header="Значение 2" />
            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

MainWindow.xaml.cs:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;

namespace WpfApplication1
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public ObservableCollection<Example> Examples { get; set; }
        public ObservableCollection<Employee> Employees { get; set; }

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();


            Employees = new ObservableCollection<Employee>()
            {
                new Employee( "Иван", 1.54, 0),
                new Employee( "Сергей", 6.48, 0),
                new Employee( "Владимир", 9.88, 0)
            };
            Examples = new ObservableCollection<Example>();

            DataContext = this;
        }
    }
}
```

Класс Employee.cs:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace WpfApplication1
{
   public  class Employee
    {
       public Employee()
       {

       }

        public Employee(string name, double value1, double value2)
        {
            Name = name;
            Value1 = value1;
            Value2 = value2;
        }

        public string Name { get; set; }
        public double Value1 { get; set; }
        public double Value2 { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Класс Example.cs: (Сделан так, что бы числа во втором столбце изменялись соответсвенно выбору элемента из ComboBox)

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace WpfApplication1
{
    public class Example : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {

        private double _value2;

        private Employee _employee;



        public Employee Employee
        {
            get { return _employee; }
            set
            {
                _employee = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged();
            }
        }


        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        // This method is called by the Set accessor of each property.
        // The CallerMemberName attribute that is applied to the optional propertyName
        // parameter causes the property name of the caller to be substituted as an argument.
        private void NotifyPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] String propertyName = "")
        {
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
            {
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: а класс Employee реализует интерфейс INPC? или вы просто забыли добавить?

Comment: К сожалению я не знаю, что такое интерфейс INPC. Дело в том что я совсем недавно начал изучать wpf. Поэтому пока очень много не знаю.

Comment: вот у вас класс Example его реализует как раз, сделайте также с Emploee и поля Value1 Value2 переделайте чтоб при изменении вызывался NotifyPropertyChanged()

Comment: Т.е. как я понимаю, надо в класс Employee внести следующие изменения:
Сделать класс Employee  типа INotifyPropertyChanged
далее добавить
public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
и
private void NotifyPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] String propertyName = "")
Только я не понимаю как Value1 Value2 переделать..

Answer (score 1):

Я думаю у вас проблема в путанице с байдингом, давайте смотреть:
1) в `MainWindow` в кодбихайнд у вас две коллекции `Examples` и `Employees` и больше ничего и вы ее делаете `DataContext = this;`
2) в XAML `DataGrid` источником служит `ItemsSource="{Binding Examples}"`
, для `ComboBox` `ItemsSource="{Binding Employees`, а далее внимание для этого же комбокса `SelectedItem="{Binding Employee`, ну и далее `Employee` еще используется. Вот и вопрос, а где у вас **свойство c названием Employee в кодбихайнд**? Посмотрите в Output во время запуска проекта не ругается ли на ошибки байдинга компилятор.

Comment: У тс Employee берется из Examples, привязка работает, я проверял, только этот SelectedItem получается то один для всех строк Examples. По идее Employees должен лежать в Example

Answer (score 0):

Как советовал S.Kost я переделал класс Employee. Однако это совсем не помогло.. 
Класс Employee имеет следующий вид:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace WpfApplication1
{
   public  class Employee : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        private double _val1;
        private double _val2;

        public Employee()
       {

       }

        public Employee(string name, double value1, double value2)
        {
            Name = name;
            Value1 = value1;
            Value2 = value2;
        }

        public string Name { get; set; }
        public double Value1
        {
            get { return _val1; }
            set
            {
                _val1 = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged();

            }
        }
        public double Value2
        {
            get { return _val2; }
            set
            {
                _val2 = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged();
            }
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        // This method is called by the Set accessor of each property.
        // The CallerMemberName attribute that is applied to the optional propertyName
        // parameter causes the property name of the caller to be substituted as an argument.
        private void NotifyPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] String propertyName = "")
        {
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
            {
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Текст пропадает потому что у вас одна коллекция для всех строк, добавлении новой строки SelectedItem этой коллекции меняется, соответственно и имя пропадает. Нужно пересмотреть архитектуру.

Answer (score 0):

Разрабатывать программу я начинал с другого варианта. А именно для первого столбца я использовал DataGridComboBoxColumn, а не DataGridTemplateColumn.

XAML для DataGrid был такой:

```
<DataGrid x:Name="DataGrid3"
          HorizontalAlignment="Center"
          VerticalAlignment="Top"
          AutoGenerateColumns="False"
          CanUserResizeRows="False"
          CanUserSortColumns="False"
          GridLinesVisibility="All"
          SelectionMode="Extended"
          SelectionUnit="Cell">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridComboBoxColumn x:Name="ComboBoxColomn3"
                                Width="200"
                                DisplayMemberPath="Name"
                                Header="Название"
                                SelectedItemBinding="{Binding Employee,
                                                              Mode=TwoWay,
                                                              UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Employee.Value1}"
                            Header="Значение 1"
                            IsReadOnly="True" />
        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Value2, Mode=TwoWay}" Header="Значение 2" />
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

При этом в коде я прописывал:

```
DataGrid3.ItemsSource = Examples;
ComboBoxColomn3.ItemsSource = Employees;
```

При этом все классы - Employee и Example были такие как я и указал в своем первом посте. И все работало впринципе так как я хотел. Но перейти на DataGridTemplateColumn захотел исключительно по причине, чтобы реализовать возможность выбрать элемент из списка в ComboBox, введя текст в текстовом поле. Но вот возникли следующие проблеммы которые я озвучивал выше..